# PHP Content-Disposition filename only works partially

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, filenames, content-disposition

I've wrote a script that display some pdf files from my server in the Browser.
This is working semi fine and if the user clicks on save, the correct filename is displayed in the dialog window.
But Chrome does not showing the correct file name.

Please see the picture, then you know what i mean:
URL: .../api/downloads/getFile/MDBhYmYzZDI2MUFFUCBIb....
[Screenhot Chrome wrong Filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZ8l.png)

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$fileNameOnServer = "MDBhYmYzZDI2MUFFUCBIb.pdf";
$file = "/media/downloads/pdf/".$fileNameOnServer;
$originalFileName = getFileNameFromSQL($fileNameOnServer);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file)."");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.rawurldecode($originalFileName).'"');
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Info about the filename: There are a lot of pdf's, and to avoid duplicates I hashed all filenames and stored the original name in a database.

Edit:

I've updated my code with the function "$originalFileName = getFileNameFromSQL($fileNameOnServer);"

This screenshot show's the "save as" dialog window with the correct FileName:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0jZj.png)

Comment: Filename is exactly shown as given. If you don't want to see the URL like that, you need to redirect to the httpdocs and have output script there.

Comment: Is your confusion because you did `rawurldecode($fileName)` instead of `rawurldecode($file)`

Comment: FWIW, there is no Content-Transfer-Encoding field in HTTP.

Comment: excuse me for confusing something
The original filename is loaded out of the sql databse and hand over as filename.
Let me update my fist post

Comment: Also: (a) please attach the header fields as seen by the browser, and (b) try with Firefox as well.